# child div click event triggers parent click event

Tags: javascript

How do i prevent the parent click event from firing if the child div is clicked?

http://jsfiddle.net/2GEKu/

```
var p = document.getElementById('parent');
var c = document.getElementById('child');

p.onclick = function () {
    alert('parent click');
}
c.onclick = function () {
    alert('child click');
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Invoke the `.stopPropagation()` method of the `event` object in the child's handler.

```
var p = document.getElementById('parent');
var c = document.getElementById('child');

p.onclick = function () {
    alert('parent click');
}
c.onclick = function (event) {
    event.stopPropagation();
    alert('child click');
}
```

---

To make it compatible with IE8 and lower, do this:

```
c.onclick = function (event) {
    if (event)
        event.stopPropagation();
    else
        window.event.cancelBubble = true;
    alert('child click');
}
```